# Is there a algorithm to compute the Schur multiplier of a finite group from a group presentation

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, computational-group-theory, schur-multipliers

Suppose we have a **finite** group $G$ whose presentation or Cayley table is given. Is there an algorithm (at least theoretically - without considering computational complexity) to compute the Cayley table or a presentation of the Schur multiplier?

If possible please refer me to a paper which talks about the algorithm.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73153/is-there-an-algorithm-for-computing-schur-multiplier). The answer is no -- it's an undecidable problem.

Comment: Wait... my group is finite

Comment: The case of when $G$ is a finite group is answered in the comments of that question, too. Those comments link you [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53730/transfer-kernels-and-the-schur-multiplier) for explicit algorithms (e.g. in GAP). Welcome to MathOverflow, by the way!

Comment: Both MAGMA and GAP can compute the Schur multiplier of a finite group. So algorithms must exist (possibly more than one).

Comment: Could you refer me to a paper which explains the algorithm

Comment: Did you try MAGMA or GAP documentation?

Comment: @Cloudjr The Wikipedia page for the [Schur multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_multiplier) has several references for this. See e.g. [this paper by Ellis & Leonard](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20490165).

Comment: I don't have access to it right now, but I believe that the following book explains algorithms for this (and many other things -- if you have computational questions in group theory, it's a good first place to look):

Holt, Derek F.; Eick, Bettina; O'Brien, Eamonn A.
Handbook of computational group theory. 
Discrete Mathematics and its Applications (Boca Raton). Chapman & Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, FL, 2005.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an algorithm for computing Schur multiplier?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73153/is-there-an-algorithm-for-computing-schur-multiplier)

Answer (score 10):

A reference is:

D.F. Holt, The calculation of the Schur multiplier of a permutation group. In: Michael D. Atkinson, Edotor, *Computational Group Theory* (Conference proceedings, Durham, 1982), Academic Press, 1984, pages 307-319.

But you might have difficulty finding it!

The idea of this algorithm is to find the $p$-parts of the multiplier separately for the primes $p$ dividing $|G|$. To do that, we first find the multiplier $M(P)$ of a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ using part of the $p$-quotient algorithm, and then find the $M(G)_p$ as the subgroup of $G$-stable elements of $G$. (I programmed this myself first in ALGOL60 and then in C in the early 1980s, partly motivated by the fact that there had been so many errors in the calculation of the multipliers of the finite simple groups - it had taken three attempts to get $M(M_{22})$ right!)

There is a much simpler algorithm available in Magma as $\mathtt{Darstellungsgruppe}$ that takes as input a finite presentation $\langle X \mid R \rangle$ of the finite group $G$, and finds a presentation of a Schur-covering group $C(G)$ of $G$ by factoring out a free abelian subgroup of $R/[F(X),R]$ in $F(X)/[F(X),R]$ using the Hopf formula. The multipler can then be calculated as the kernel of the natural map $C(G) \to G$. This works OK but only for moderately small groups $G$. Here is an example with $G=A_5$.

```
> G:=Group<x,y|x^2,y^3,(x*y)^5>;
> C,phi:=Darstellungsgruppe(G);
> K:=Kernel(phi);
> #K;
  2
```

Comment: For the interested, the proceedings (and thus the article) can be found by searching for "Computational group theory: Proc. London MS symposium" in whatever pseudo-legal book repository one knows of.